# Ruby .split (various delimiters) keep delimiters in match array

Tags: ruby, regex

I'm dealing with an export file that contains a note field in an exported .csv file.  The notes exported look like this.

"AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect. AC) dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect. WDB) Dianne - Wrong Number. AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect."

Within this field we have a user who left the note and the actual note itself.

The delimiters in the files are "AC)" or "WDB)"

I need to write these as:

```
AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
AC) dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
WDB) Dianne - Wrong Number.
AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
```

Using a regular expression and the ruby function .split I can output the text following the delimiter but I lose the user who captured the notes.

**Ruby**

```
notes.split( /AC\)|WDB\)/ ).each do |n|
    puts n  
end
```

**Output**

```
Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
Dianne - Wrong Number.
Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
```

In the code above I have no idea who the user (AC, WDB) who left the individual note.

I'm not sure if I need to switch to a .scan, alter the regex (ie. include a lookbehind), etc.
Does anyone have any idea how I can capture the user and text to look like this?

**Output**

```
AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
AC) dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
WDB) Dianne - Wrong Number.
AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just split the input according to the below lookahead,

```
(?=AC\)|WDB\))
```

Lookarounds are zero width assertions. It won't match any character but it was used for condition checking purposes.

**Code:**

```
> "AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect. AC) dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect. WDB) Dianne - Wrong Number. AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect.".split(/(?=AC\)|WDB\))/)
=> ["AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect. ", "AC) dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect. ", "WDB) Dianne - Wrong Number. ", "AC) Dianne - # or code dialed is incorrect."]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this -

```
notes.gsub!(/\s+((?:AC\))|(?:WDB\)))/, '\n\1')
```

Test out the regex [here](http://regex101.com/r/qU9eF3/1)